# ImportError: cannot import name _distributor_init

Tags: python, scipy, pip

While trying to import `scipy`, I'm getting the following error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-4dc45f4c0083> in <module>()
----> 1 import scipy

C:\Users\admin\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py in <module>()
     74 
     75 # Allow distributors to run custom init code
---> 76 from . import _distributor_init
     77 
     78 __all__ += _num.__all__

ImportError: cannot import name _distributor_init
```

I have tried re-installing from pip by force reinstall, it says that scipy is up-to-date but then, loading it gives the above error. How do I resolve it? I'm using **Python 2.x** version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting the same error while using cx_freeze, i managed to make it work by simply commenting this line in the **init**.py of scipy (---> 76 from . import _distributor_init). 
From what i read there: [[Numpy-discussion] Hook in **init**.py to let distributors patch numpy](https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2016-February/074930.html)
it simply enables more customization of checks, that i didn't need.
Scipy seems to work just fine without it.
Fyi I installed scipy without using anaconda, and i use python 3.6.
Hope this helps.

Comment: If I try and comment the line I get the following error:IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
Here is how to proceed:
- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
- If you are simply trying to use the numpy version that you have installed:
  your installation is broken - please reinstall numpy.

Answer (score 1):

I use [cx_Freeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/) and package have this error. I add this code to solve this problem:

```
self.build_exe_options = {
    'includes': "scipy._distributor_init"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

just upgrade your sklearn, upgrade everything and u will be fine

Comment: Could you provide some command line snippet for upgrading if you think it would help the OP?